# How to parse this string in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string-parsing

I have the following string in python:

```
text = "vagrant  11450  4344  0 Feb22 pts/2    00:00:28 python run.py abc"
```

I want to capture the text after time field that is "python run.py abc"

I am using the following regex but it is not working

```
 [\d:]+ (.)*
```

Comment: Use `r'\d+:\d+\s+(.*)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its perfectly working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
\d+:\d+\s+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVFT7B/1).

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `:` - a colon
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (the value you need to access using `.group(1)`): any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (all the rest of the line).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nYYO2x):

```
import re
text = "vagrant  11450  4344  0 Feb22 pts/2    00:00:28 python run.py abc"
m = re.search(r'\d+:\d+\s+(.*)', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => python run.py abc
```

Answer (score 1):

With `re.search()` function:

```
import re

text = "vagrant  11450  4344  0 Feb22 pts/2    00:00:28 python run.py abc"
result = re.search(r'(?<=(\d{2}:){2}\d{2} ).*', text).group()

print(result)
```

The output:

```
python run.py abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Without RE:

```
text = "vagrant  11450  4344  0 Feb22 pts/2    00:00:28 python run.py abc"
text=text.split(":")[-1][3:]
```

Output:

```
python run.py abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` and regex [`:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/i3hSW1/1).

```
text = 'vagrant  11450  4344  0 Feb22 pts/2    00:00:28 python run.py abc'
str = re.split(r':\d{2}:\d{2}\s+', text)[1]
```

Output: `python run.py abc`

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/XN5YwY)